# Using value_counts in pandas with conditions

Tags: pandas

I have a column with around 20k values. I've used the following function in pandas to display their counts:

```
weather_data["snowfall"].value_counts()
```

`weather_data` is the dataframe and `snowfall` is the column.

My results are:

```
0.0     12683
M       7224
T       311
0.2     32
0.1     31
0.5     20
0.3     18
1.0     14
0.4     13
```

etc.

Is there a way to:

1. Display the counts of only a single variable or number
2. Use an if condition to display the counts of only those values which satisfy the condition?

Comment: 1.  Yes.  2. Yes.  You'll need to do a bit more work demonstrating what you've tried and researched.

Comment: @piRSquared Appreciate you responding yes to both. Now, could you tell how to do it?

Comment: My point was, you were not nearly specific enough for me to answer.  I could generate an example but that is work you should've done.  Consider reading these 2 posts on asking questions.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  and   http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm genuinely lost at what you want me to be more specific about. I understand it might sound gibberish to anyone not having the same issue I'm having, but I can't see what the trip up is here. Could you please provide an example or tell me what exactly the problem is?

Comment: I'll be as direct as possible.  Stackoverflow is not a coding service.  The intent is provide a forum for those who are coding to ask questions of other coders.  What you've done is asked a question without demonstrating that you've done any work to help yourself first.  If you read through the links I provided, you'll have a much better idea on how to ask a question.  It should also provide you with a framework that may help you answer your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll be as clear as possible without having a full example as piRSquared suggested you to provide.

`value_counts`' output is a `Series`, therefore the values in your originale `Series` can be retrieved from the value_counts' index. Displaying only the result of one of the variables then is exactly slicing your series:

```
my_value_count = weather_data["snowfall"].value_counts()
my_value_count.loc['0.0']
output: 
0.0     12683
```

If you want to display only for a list of variables:

```
my_value_count.loc[my_value_count.index.isin(['0.0','0.2','0.1'])]
output: 
0.0     12683
0.2     32
0.1     31
```

As you have `M` and `T` in your values, I suspect the other values will be treated as strings and not float. Otherwise you could use:

```
my_value_count.loc[my_value_count.index < 0.4]
output:
0.0     12683
0.2     32
0.1     31
0.3     18
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: @PratheerthPadman You're welcome. Don't forget to accept an answer to help future users who might have the same problem! Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Use an if condition to display the counts of only those values which satisfy the condition?

First create a new column based on the condition you want. Then you can use `groupby` and `sum`.

For example, if you want to count the frequency only if a column has a non-null value. In my case, if there is an actual `completion_date` non-null value:

```
dataset['Has_actual_completion_date']  = np.where(dataset['ACTUAL_COMPLETION_DATE'].isnull(), 0, 1)
dataset['Mitigation_Plans_in_progress'] = dataset['Has_actual_completion_date'].groupby(dataset['HAZARD_ID']).transform('sum')
```